# Asyncpg incorrectly displays real numbers from postgresql

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, asyncpg

There is a table with a field of type real. I save the value 1.3 to it, execute select in asyncpg(python 3) and it returns this number in this form 1.2999999523162842.
I would like to get what I have saved

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/ - if you want to retrieve exactly the same value that you stored, use `numeric` not `real`

Comment: Complain to asyncpg.  psycopg2 seems to gets this correct, so it isn't a generic problem with PostgreSQL.  Or make the column be double precision rather than real, in which case asyncpg gets it correct too.

Comment: It is not wrong, it is your expectation that is wrong. All *floating point values* are estimates. This is because it is virtually impossible to represent a decimal (base 10) non-integer exactly in binary (base 2).  You may also want to Google **IEEE 754**. The best you can do is use the largest representation available, i.e. prefer double precision over float (real), or in Postgres use `numeric`.